# Cardo e Decumano

Tags: word-usage

> In molte città moderne è ancora evidente la struttura a forma di croce, eredità del ***castrum***, *l’accampamento romano che si distingueva per la pianta ortogonale e le strade tra di loro perpendicolari chiamate* ***Cardo e Decumano***.
>
> - È proprio a questa struttura che si ispira il disegno del Sito Espositivo di Expo Milano 2015. Semplice e intuitivo, il progetto gestisce in modo inedito la partecipazione dei Paesi e aiuta il visitatore a orientarsi all’interno dell’area tra esperienze, racconti, eventi e mostre da cui partire per assaporare i gusti delle tradizioni enogastronomiche del Pianeta. Un vero e proprio giro del mondo!
>   [image]

Quali sono i termini contemporanei per riferirsi a queste grandi vie ancora presenti in molte nostre città? I termini romani sono ancora usati in contesti  tecnici ad esempio?

[image]

Comment: Grazie per aver messo l’immagine di Verona, che m’è cara. :-) Comunque, dal momento che queste vie furono costruite in epoca romana e permangono tuttora, non c’è motivo per cambiarne la denominazione. Ciò è particolarmente vero in «contesti tecnici», cioè in archeologia, urbanistica, ecc. [Qui](https://www.google.it/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cardo+decumano&tbm=bks) qualche esempio (non selezionato, ovviamente, ma spulciando i risultati si trovano testi specialistici).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I termini romani *decumano* e *cardo* (ma sarebbe piú coerente *cardine*) hanno connotazione tecnico-specialistica:

> **[decumano](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/decumano)**
>   **TS** stor.
>   […]
>   **3.** s.m., strada che attraversava da est a ovest l’accampamento o la città romana
>
> **[cardo](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cardo_2) TS** stor. negli accampamenti militari romani, la via principale che andava da nord a sud

Sono questi termini a designare le due grandi strade che caratterizzano molte città d’impianto romano. Non ci sono sinonimi; esiste soltanto la variante adattata di *cardo*, *[cardine](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/cardine)*.

Comment: È vero, sarebbe più coerente “cardine”, ma allora dovremmo dire anche “uòmine” anziché “uomo”.  ;-)

Comment: Beh, non è proprio la stessa cosa. `;-)` _Cardo_ o _cardine_ sono parole di tradizione culta; _uomo_ è una parola di tradizione ininterrotta. Il mio richiamo alla coerenza ha senso solo se applicato a una coppia di cultismi, come _cardo_ e _decumano_: _cardo_ è un nominativo, ciò che rende la parola un latinismo non adattato (un po’ come se si scrivesse _urbs_), mentre le parole italiane, _di norma_, derivano dall’accusativo (alcune eccezioni: _uomo_, _sarto_, _moglie_, ecc.). Allora o usiamo solo il latino — _cardo_ e _decumanus_ — o adattiamo i termini in _cardine_ e _decumano_.

Comment: La questione lascia però il tempo che trova: come conferma il _De Mauro_, l’uso ha stabilito la prevalenza di _cardo_, anche per distinguere, anche sotto l’aspetto del significante, il significato tecnico-specialistico di cui discutiamo.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con te su tutta la linea: il mio era solo un commento al volo per ricordare – come fai tu stesso nei tuoi commenti – che dall'evoluzione linguistica non si può pretendere sempre la “coerenza”.

Answer (score -2):

Non posso dire nulla sulla terminologia tecnica, ma non credo ci siano termini di uso comune che si riferiscano nello specifico a quelle vie.

Sono rimasti in italiano il sostantivo `cardine` e l'aggettivo `cardinale`. Il primo può indicare la base, il fondamento di qualcosa:

> Il punto cardine della teoria

ma anche una delle due parti del meccanismo (cerniera) che pemette di aprire e chiudere una porta

> ...portone di legno che si reggeva a malapena sui cardini arrugginiti...

[link](https://books.google.ch/books?id=0cACV51frdMC&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=si+reggeva+su+cardini+arrugginiti&source=bl&ots=75mLkGUW70&sig=52HTlIKdTJiXsm2MzDmP8OvT4Ok&hl=it&sa=X&ei=8M9JVaTLC9P5ap_agZgF&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=si%20reggeva%20su%20cardini%20arrugginiti&f=false)

Cardinale, come aggettivo, da non confondere con il sostantivo che indica i prelati della Chiesa, indica ciò che fa da cardine, che è principale:

> i principi cardinali della teoria esposta

Non sono quindi rimasti riferimenti architettonici specifici e non vi è più traccia del termine `decumano` nell'uso comune.

Comment: Il downvote non  é mio, ma penso che si riferisca al fatto che la risposta è poco focalizzata sulla domanda.

Comment: Il downvote è mio, perché mi sembra una (non-)risposta inutile: esordisce dicendo “non posso dire nulla ... non credo ...” e poi si mette a parlare di tutt'altro (un'altra parola che condivide solo un nesso etimologico, ma non il significato, con una delle due su cui verteva la domanda).

Comment: Non sono sufficientemente esperto di stackexchange, non so bene la netiquette e dunque mi scuso per l'errore tra risposta e commento.
Ad ogni modo, non posso parlare del contesto tecnico (parte della domanda), ma in italiano contemporaneo (altra parte della domanda) non esistono termini che indichino le vie principali nord-sud ed est-ovest. Corsi, viali o altra terminologia non hanno indicazioni circa la disposizione geografica. Il "non credo" e' legato allo smodato uso di IMHO che faccio in altri contesti su internet, per non urtare le opinioni altrui, cosa che qui non è richiesta, giusto?

Comment: È giustissimo essere cauti e garbati (e probabilmente io non lo sono abbastanza), ma il fatto è appunto che qui non si parla di “opinioni”. Se hai un buon motivo per credere che non esistano termini moderni analoghi a “cardo” e “decumano” (un articolo esistente, una tua ricerca, un ragionamento solido...), esponili. Tutto qui.

Comment: Non c'è problema. Mi sorge un dubbio: riportare l'assenza di sinonimi nei maggiori vocabolari di italiano è motivo sufficiente? Perché io ne ho controllati un discreto numero e non vi è alcun utilizzo contemporaneo di cardo o decumano.